# Using Eclipse MAT Not able to find Memory leak created by Array Object

Tags: java, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I am debugging a OutOfMemory issue using MAT( Analyzing Heap Dump ) in old java application.
MAT shows a RMI Thread has created Array(BO[150K+]) of My Business Object(BO) which has 150k+ instances, it is consuming around 358 MB ( Xmx is 512 MB). It is a memory leak situation.

One more interesting part I noticed in all the dumps ( created after server crash ) number of instances in Array Object is same.

I am not able to understand how can I find out this Array Object , in which class this array object is created. is there any such direct/indirect feature available in MAT ?

please suggest if any such option available in visualVM or some other tool. Or Some memory analyzer which i can run over codebase.

Comment: Im pretty sure that visualVM connects to a JVM instance on an RMI TCP Connection thread. MAT might as well. Are you experiencing the memory leak while not profiling with MAT? Also is your application JMX enabled?

Comment: @MarkW Yes I am analyzing heap dump now using MAT.

Comment: what I mean is that, we had a similar issue here related to JMX. We enabled JMX in our application, but shortsightedness caused us to instrument short lived objects, which were being maintained via their MBean registration. We refactored code to hold weak references to these objects and the problem went away. Also the leak only ever manifested if the applications MBean server was running.

Comment: @MarkW In My application such hign number of instances are not possible so something is wrong in the code. But I am not able to figure out what is going wrong. Initially i though some static array we are using and in all RMI calls we are adding Business Objects to same static Array Field , But I do not see any such static Array in code.

Comment: http://visualvm.java.net/heapdump.html this may help, see the Instances View section.

Comment: i saw that but it doesn't tell where that Array is created , I mean in which class this Array is defined.

Answer (score 1):

in Eclipse MAT histogram select the array object and right click and select the

`"merge shortest path to GC Root" (exclude weak references) ,`

this should show you the creation path all the way upto the base class object which creates this array.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you need a profiler that can show you where instances were allocated, you can try [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html). The heap walker has an "Allocations" view where you can see the cumulated call stacks for any set of objects. To get allocation call stacks, you have to switch on allocation recording, possibly at startup.

[image]

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler

Answer (score 0):

There is functionality to use OQL on your heap dump in vanilla jVisualVM. One of the functions in OQL is heap.livepaths, which takes an instance as a parameter and outputs all paths that prevent garbage collection.
If you have a concrete class or object that you know should not be there (relevant windows closed for swing and garbage collector forced several times), you can just list those paths and get several examples of reference paths.
Rinse and repeat until all suspect objects DO get garbage collected. Then it becomes more difficult since you no longer have a lead, but you likely found several bugs in your app and may have fixed it to an acceptable degree.

Note: I usually go the hard way around analyzing memory leaks, and it may not work for very complex applications.